# Optimize PostgreSQL join with array_agg (8000 rows but takes too long)

Tags: postgresql

```
WITH transformed_payment_in_record_details AS (
  SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.nickname AS external_party_nickname,
    t2.username AS external_party_username
  FROM accounting.payment_in_record_details AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
    accounting.external_parties AS t2
      ON t1.external_party_id = t2.object_id
), transformed_payment_in_records AS (
  SELECT
    t1.*,
    COALESCE((SELECT to_json(
      array_agg(transformed_payment_in_record_details)
    )
              FROM transformed_payment_in_record_details
              WHERE t1.object_id = transformed_payment_in_record_details.payment_in_record_id), '[]') AS details,
    t2.username                                                                                       AS reported_by_username,
    t2.nickname                                                                                       AS reported_by_nickname,
    t3.username                                                                                       AS status_changed_by_username,
    t3.nickname                                                                                       AS status_changed_by_nickname,
    t4.identifier                                                                                     AS to_payment_system_identifier,
    t4.name                                                                                           AS to_payment_system_name,
    t4.owner_name                                                                                     AS to_payment_system_owner_name
  FROM
    accounting.payment_in_records AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounting.users AS t2
      ON t1.reported_by_id = t2.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounting.users AS t3
      ON t1.status_changed_by_id = t3.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounting.payment_systems AS t4
      ON t1.to_payment_system_id = t4.object_id
)
SELECT *
FROM transformed_payment_in_records;
```

The problem lies in this section

```
   COALESCE((SELECT to_json(
      array_agg(transformed_payment_in_record_details)
    )
              FROM transformed_payment_in_record_details
              WHERE t1.object_id = transformed_payment_in_record_details.payment_in_record_id), '[]') AS details,
```

So I have three tables

- payment_in_records
- payment_in_record_details
- external_parties

1 payment_in_record can have MANY payment_in_record_details. Each payment_in_record_detail contain reference to external_parties, that is why I need to join that to get username and nickname first.

This query is running against 8000 rows. I have no index implemented. I wonder what can be done to optimize the speed? When I use OFFSET, LIMIT, it takes quite long 10-20 seconds to respond.

```
Limit  (cost=138861.47..138861.49 rows=10 width=409) (actual time=404.772..404.775 rows=10 loops=1)
  CTE transformed_payment_in_records
    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=57.00..138487.18 rows=8293 width=402) (actual time=0.193..363.731 rows=8293 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (t1.to_payment_system_id = t4.object_id)
          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=37.55..524.04 rows=8293 width=302) (actual time=0.088..19.782 rows=8293 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (t1.status_changed_by_id = t3.object_id)
                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=18.77..392.73 rows=8293 width=238) (actual time=0.050..14.023 rows=8293 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: (t1.reported_by_id = t2.object_id)
                      ->  Seq Scan on payment_in_records t1  (cost=0.00..259.93 rows=8293 width=174) (actual time=0.009..3.605 rows=8293 loops=1)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=13.90..13.90 rows=390 width=80) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=20 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on users t2  (cost=0.00..13.90 rows=390 width=80) (actual time=0.006..0.014 rows=20 loops=1)
                ->  Hash  (cost=13.90..13.90 rows=390 width=80) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=20 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                      ->  Seq Scan on users t3  (cost=0.00..13.90 rows=390 width=80) (actual time=0.003..0.011 rows=20 loops=1)
          ->  Hash  (cost=14.20..14.20 rows=420 width=84) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=28 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                ->  Seq Scan on payment_systems t4  (cost=0.00..14.20 rows=420 width=84) (actual time=0.006..0.017 rows=28 loops=1)
          SubPlan 1
            ->  Aggregate  (cost=16.61..16.62 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=1 loops=8293)
                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..16.60 rows=1 width=145) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=8293)
                        ->  Index Scan using payment_in_record_details_payment_in_record_id_fkey on payment_in_record_details t11  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=8293)
                              Index Cond: (t1.object_id = payment_in_record_id)
                        ->  Index Scan using external_parties_pkey on external_parties t22  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=8203)
                              Index Cond: (t11.external_party_id = object_id)
  ->  Sort  (cost=373.04..383.41 rows=4146 width=409) (actual time=404.648..404.757 rows=510 loops=1)
        Sort Key: transformed_payment_in_records.created_timestamp DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 476kB
        ->  CTE Scan on transformed_payment_in_records  (cost=0.00..165.86 rows=4146 width=409) (actual time=0.196..394.805 rows=8293 loops=1)
              Filter: (NOT removed)
Planning time: 1.199 ms
Execution time: 423.758 ms
```

Comment: It is probably because you *have no index implemented* that it is slow. Every column involved in the joins should be indexed in some form, either as the primary key of a table or as a foreign key to another table. Have you considered using an explain plan to help optimize your queries?

Comment: @Used_By_Already hi, can you please simply explain to me what column should be indexed? I have trouble figuring out which coloumn needed to be indexed when joined of two tables are involved. And about array_agg, what can i know about what index column should it bE?

Comment: I would turn the `WITH` clauses into subselects in the `FROM` clause. That way the optimizer has a chance to find a better plan.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you! actually i did just that and it is much faster. I am still curious why this is the case though? I keep finding resource online but nothing really address my current senario

Comment: The reason is that CTE act as "optimization fences" in PostgreSQL: the optimizer optimizes the CTE, but the CTE is always optimized independent from the rest, even when the way that the CTE is used would suggest an optimization.

Comment: BTW: `Execution time: 423.758 ms` is not 10..20 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes should exist on these columns I believe:

```
accounting.payment_in_records.reported_by_id
accounting.payment_in_records.status_changed_by_id
accounting.payment_in_records.to_payment_system_id

transformed_payment_in_record_details.payment_in_record_id
accounting.users.object_id
accounting.payment_systems.object_id
```

All I did was look at each join (or the correlation in the subquery) and list the columns that are involved in those: No magic needed.

Comment: Hi, i went ahead and create indexes for main tables. One question, for CTE table that is creating with "WITH" statement, will they use the underlying index of the main table? or i must create another index explicity for that query?

Comment: The CTE will use the underlying indexes

Comment: Hi, i created the index, it is still very slow. I am trying to find a way to optimize array_agg part. Do you have any insight on what i can do?

Comment: I attached an analyze